# Como redirecionar página em JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2, xhtml

Tenho um sistema com um formulário no qual se pode editar ou remover itens.
Nele há um link para redirecionar outra página.

[image: telaFormulario]

De que formar é possível redirecionar uma página em JSF?

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032825/how-to-make-a-redirection-in-jsf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Redirecionar* é um termo específico.
Você pode *redirecionar* ou *encaminhar*:

---

### Encaminhar

Encaminhar significa levar o usuário para outra página **dentro do mesmo contexto** sem que seja feita uma nova requisição.
Dessa forma, a URL na barra de endereços do navegador não muda. Continua com o endereço da página antiga.
Ex:

```
@ManagedBean
public class TesteMB {

    public String encaminha() {
        return "pagina";
    }
}
```

---

### Redirecionar

Redirecionar significa fazer uma nova requisição. O redirecionamento **pode** apontar para páginas fora do contexto (www.uol.com.br, por exemplo).
Ao redirecionar a URL da barra de endereço é alterada, sendo atualizada para o endereço da página em questão.
Ex:

```
@ManagedBean
public class TesteMB {

    public String redireciona() {
        return "pagina?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

---

Repare que em nenhum dos dois casos foi necessário incluir a extensão de `pagina`.
Isso é opcional.

---

### XHTML

No XHTML utilize o atributo `action` dentro da tag desejada.
Ex:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{testeMB.encaminha}" />
<p:commandButton action="#{testeMB.redirectiona}" />
```